# Как правильно добавить DISTINCT в MySQL запрос

Tags: mysql, запрос

Есть запрос на подсчёт количества активных сессий из таблицы:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM sessions WHERE last_active >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE);
```

В таблице существует поля **SESSIONID**, **uid**, **last_active**. В поле **uid** содержится **ID** аккаунта. Во всех остальных случаях (гость, поисковый бот) оно равно нулю. Подскажите, как правильно добавить *DISTINCT* чтобы отбросить из статистики мультисессии пользователей и засчитывать их как одну, по условию когда `uid > 0`?

Comment: покажите пример тестовых данных - 5-6 записей и результат, который хотите получить в результате запроса

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis нет под рукой базы данных, объясню подробнее. Есть 10 произвольных записей сессий в таблице с uin = 0. Эти записи относятся к поисковым ботам и гостям. А есть две записи сессий с uin = 2. Т.е. какой-то пользователь авторизован и сидит на сайте с двух устройств. Мой пример запроса при таком содержании таблицы выведет количество равное 12. А мне нужно игнорировать мультисессии и результат должен быть 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, что вам нужно:

```
SELECT count(distinct if(uid!=0, uid, SESSIONID) )
  FROM sessions
 WHERE last_active >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE);
```

Т.е. для uid не равных 0 считаем количества уникальных uid, а для равных 0 считаем количества уникальных сессий.

И работает корректно в случае если uid и SESSIONID значения из совершенно разных плоскостей и между собой никак пересекаться не могут. Если могут - то добавьте к сессии какой нибудь префикс, например.

Comment: Спасибо. Работает как нужно. Два пользователя с мультесессиями воспринялись как 2, а не 4. Я был в шаге к вашему варианту до создания вопроса, но по неопытности я вместо SESSIONID указал null. Теперь я понял как работает это условие.

Answer (score 1):

Если решение Mike не подходит, можно использовать вот этот запрос

```
select count(case when uid=0 then uid end)+ 
count( distinct case when uid!=0 then uid end) 
FROM sessions
WHERE last_active >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE);
```

[Фиддл](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b756405e7fcd93f96e720a52e37c143e)

Comment: Ваш запрос тоже работает. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM sessions WHERE uid > 0
```

Comment: К сожалению это не то.

Comment: distinct в `select *` в принципе ничего сделать не может, так как набор из всех полей таблицы гарантированно уникален (при наличии хоть одного первичного/уникального ключа).

Answer (score 0):

Игнорим мультсессии значит не выводим их

```
Select distinct uid from sessions where uid>0
```

А на самом деле лучше сгруппировать и получить ещё количество сессий

```
Select uid, count(*) from sessions where uid>0 group by uid
```

Я только гадаю, возможно так вы хотите

```
 SELECT count(distinct uid) FROM sessions WHERE last_active >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) and uid >0
```

Хотите можно и по сложнее

```
 Select count( distinct case when uid>0 then uid else null end) from ....
```

Comment: К сожалению это не то.

Comment: А что на самом деле вам нужно?

Comment: Давайте исправим на нужное вам

Comment: Я же в вопросе описал проблему. На данный момент мой запрос учитывает мультисессии пользователей. Мне нужно избавиться от этого сгруппировав мультисессии в одну по условию что UIN > 0 чтобы все боты и гости не сжались в одну единственную сессию.

Comment: А последний запрос мне даёт результат который нужен?

Comment: Я это уже пробовал прежде чем задать вопрос. А также пробовал более сложные условия вида **`count(DISTINCT IF (uid > 0, 1, 0))`. Но я не очень хорошо разбираюсь в SQL синтаксисе.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110691/discussion-between-aziz-umarov-and-rootware).